# Azure webjobs schedule based, when to shut down host?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-webjobs

I have a long running process (ex. sending newsletter or crawling) in a scheduled based webjobs, should I manually stop the host after the process is done?

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Initialize();
        JobHost host = new JobHost();
        TestNoTrigger();

    }

    [NoAutomaticTrigger]
    public static void TestNoTrigger()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++)
        {
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(4000);
            Console.WriteLine(i);
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need the `JobHost` in your scenario. You only need it if you use `JobHost.Call` to invoke that manual function.

The way you are doing it, `TestNoTrigger` is just a C# method call without anything special.